# MPTT to select root element mysql

Tags: mysql, mptt

What mysql query should i use to select root elements? Let's say i have tree structure like this:
http://www.ipix.lt/desc/18496369
And i want to select (Vaisiai, Daržovės) elements.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have the 'root elements' as children of an actual and unused root element. 
Then you can select the children of that root, and you have what you are looking for.
Just an idea, and very late answer, it seems.